# Why does my pure CSS slider menu not work?

Tags: html, css

Here's a CSS slider I'm working on and I can't find where I went wrong. It's supposed to slide over on clicking the hamburger menu and then display the contents. Where did I go wrong? How do I get the contents of the menu to appear? Are my z-indexes all wrong?

```css
    h1 {
      margin-top: 10px;
      font-family: 'Reenie Beanie', cursive;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      color: #0AEEFA;
      font-size: 99px;
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: 25%;
      }

    h1:hover {
      color: #ff0dbf;
      }

    img {
      width: 60%;
      padding-bottom: 80px;
      }

    #left{
      position: relative;

      width: 20%;
      float: left;
      border-style: none;
      border-width: 5px;
      border-color: #40E0D0;
      padding-top: 150px;
      }

    #name {display: none;}

    p {
      display: inline;
      margin-left: 20px;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', cursive;
      font-size: 11px;
      color: #ff0dbf;
      }

    p:hover {
      background-color: #FFA07A;
      color: blue;
      }

    #place {display: none;}

    #right{
      width: 78%;      
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
      padding-top: 150px;
      }

    #sounds {display: none;}
  
    #topnav {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 100%;
        left: 0;
        }

    ul {
      margin: 0;
      list-style-type:none;
      text-align: center;
      }


#container {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
        padding: 4em;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, 
                      rgb(254,255,255) 0%,
                      rgb(221,241,249) 35%,
                      rgb(160,216,239) 100%);
    background-size: 200%;

}
.navigation {
    list-style: none;
    background: #111;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

.nav-trigger {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}


label[for="nav-trigger"] {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='1.1' x='0px' y='0px' width='30px' height='30px' viewBox='0 0 30 30' enable-background='new 0 0 30 30' xml:space='preserve'><rect width='30' height='6'/><rect y='24' width='30' height='6'/><rect y='12' width='30' height='6'/></svg>");
    background-size: contain;
}

.nav-trigger:checked + label {
    left: 215px;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .container {
    left: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.nav-trigger + label, .container {
    transition: left 0.2s;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.nav-item {
  width: 200px;
  border-top: 1px solid #111;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.nav-item a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.2s, background 0.5s;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
  color: #c74438;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(75,20,20,0.65) 100%);
}

*,*:before,*:after{
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
<label for="nav-trigger"></label>


<div id="container">

      <div id="topnav">
        <h1>photos</h1>
      </div>
      
      <div id="left"><P>Hello for looking at my pictures</P>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <P>Some are good</P>
          </li>
          <li>
            <P>Some are better</P>
          </li>
          <li>
            <P>Occassionally bad</P>
          </li>
          <li>
            <P>(end of list)</P>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    

      <div id="right">
        <ul>
          <li class = "first"><a href="Slide01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"</a> <img src="P1010821.jpg"></li><p id= "name"></a>Chris Gage, <p id ="place"><em>Chinatown somewhere -time</p></em><p id="sounds">shazam!</p>
          
          <li><a href="Slide02.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2"</a> <img src="P1010807.jpg"></li><p id= "name"></a>Chris Gage, <em><p id ="place">Tattoo joint; the owner's a rat</p></em><p id="sounds">kerrrpow!</p>
          
          <li><a href="Slide03.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2"</a> <img src="P1010777.jpg"></li><p id= "name"></a>Chris Gage, <em><p id ="place">Turck [sic] bumper</p></em><p id="sounds">thwack!</p>
          
          <li><a href="Slide04.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2"</a> <img src="P1010821.jpg"></li><p id= "name"></a>Chris Gage, <em><p id ="place">Tote things, sir</p></em><p id="sounds">zap!</p>
          
          <li><a href="Slide05.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2"</a> <img src="P1010444.jpg"></li><p id= "name"></a>Chris Gage, <em><p id ="place">This one I call colorful</p></em><p id="sounds">ooof!</p>
          
          <li><a href="Slide06.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2"</a><img src="P1010474.jpg"></li><p id= "name"></a>Chris Gage, <em><p id ="place">Color part II</p></em><p id="sounds">whammy pow!</p>
          
          <li><a href="Slide07.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2"</a><img src="P1010482.jpg"></li><p id= "name"></a>Chris Gage, <em><p id ="place">Bride-to-be</p></em><p id="sounds">zing blast!</p>
          
          <li><a href="Slide08.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2"</a><img src="P1010500.jpg"></li><p id= "name"></a>Chris Gage, <em><p id ="place">We got along famously</p></em><p id="sounds">grrr argh!</p>
      
          <li><a href="Slide09.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2"</a><img src="P1010505.jpg"></li><p id= "name"></a>Chris Gage, <em><p id ="place">Okay, not too famously</p></em><p id="sounds">womp bam!</p>
      
          <li><a href="Slide10.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2"</a><img src="P1010927.jpg"></li><p id= "name"></a>Chris Gage, <em><p id ="place">Saw red, said nothing</p></em><p id="sounds">slap punch kick!</p>
        </ul>
      </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You have errors in your code. You are not closing most of your `a` anchors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it contains a multitude of fundamental errors best solved by a good book on the subject or reading the spec.

Comment: @Rob Sorry, self-taught (evidently poorly). This is better, yes? <div class="right">
        <ul>
          <li class = "first"></li>
          <li><a href="Slide01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" /></li>
          <li><img src="P1010821.jpg" /><br></li>
          <li><p class= "name">Chris Gage,</p></li>
          <li><p class ="place"><em>Chinatown somewhere -time</em></p></li>
          <li><p class="sounds">shazam!</p></li>
        </ul>

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a lot of duplicated ids. In HTML, CSS and JavaScript, duplicated ids doesn't work very well. If you would like to add style to multiple elements you should use a class. I would suggest looking into CSS advanced selectors for making a pure slider. I do not have a specific answer but take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: I'll take a look. Appreciate it. When I went through the code and fixed up some of the IDs to classes, it worked. Wish I knew what was meant by <p>...<a> combinations that are wrong.